# Extract From Cursor-Based Pagination URL from HTTP Request Response Headers - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I am using Google Apps Script to make a series of HTTP Requests. The endpoint I have been using just switched to cursor-based pagination.

The response looks like this.

```
{...
 Link=
  <https://x.shopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/inventory_levels.json?limit=250&page_info=abc>;rel="previous",
  <https://x.shopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/inventory_levels.json?limit=250&page_info=def>;rel="next"
}
```

I can use `response['Link']` to get it down to

```
<https://x.shopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/inventory_levels.json?limit=250&page_info=abc>;rel="previous",
<https://x.shopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/inventory_levels.json?limit=250&page_info=def>;rel="next"
```

Is there a way to extract `page_info` reliably from the `"next"` URL without regular expression? I am fine resorting to regular expression but I wondered if there was specific method for getting it.

Thanks in advance for your help. I dabble and get that I still have a ton to learn.

Comment: Split by `?`, then by `&` and `=`.

Comment: I did try that one and it works fine. I was just hoping there was a "prettier" method. Oh well as long as the result is the same. I wish they would have used an array or another object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to extract the URL and whether the link is the next or previous page.

```
/<(.*)>; rel=\"(.*)\"/
```

To use this against your code you you could do something like this:

```
const urls = headers.links.map(link => {
  const linkContents = link.match(/<(.*)>; rel=\"(.*)\"/)

  const url = linkContents[1]
  const type = linkContents[2] // next or previous

  return { url, type }
})
```